# how to use mouse_event to move mouse cursor in windows login screen?

Tags: c++, winapi, vb6

there is a same question in:

[SetCursorPos and GetCursorPos not working at login screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964149/setcursorpos-and-getcursorpos-not-working-at-login-screen)

the answer as resovled was

> Alternative solution: It is possible (but very tricky) to use
>   mouse_event (which does work at login screen) instead of SetCursorPos.
>   I don't have time to post code now, but if asked I may update this
>   answer...

so, does anybody know how to use `mouse_event` to move mouse cursor in windows login screen? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found can use WinIo to send mouse and keyboard event, it is driver level, so can using in windows login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, 20000, 20000, 0, 0);
```

Note the dx and dy parameters on in the range of 0 and 65535 and not the actual screen coordinates. I suppose you could convert them if you wanted to. Also, you can leave out the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag if you want to move the pointer relative to it's last position.

Comment: thanks for reply, but your method is seems like not working in windows login screen..